# REST Services or Repeat Control with Java Object in a Data Table

Tags: xpages

Over the past couple of years or so I have revamped most of my Notes Applications for XPages and of late made extensive use of Java objects in Repeat Controls etc.

I am now implementing, where appropriate, jQuery DataTables in an attempt to generate the same functionality as Notes Views where appropriate. My applications vary from a few document records to several thousand.

Most of the Data Table tutorials etc seem to imply or recommend the use of REST Services for Data Tables. What is the reason for this when I can simply drop my existing Java Objects into Repeat Controls and then access the back end documents via links etc.

Sorry if this is not a coding question, but I am clearly missing something fundamental in my basic knowledge. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version is that jQuery data tables are built by purely (CS)JS, meaning any "normal" transport of data like a REST service (such as how you're describing using `xp:restService`) is pretty standard and ubiquitous. jQuery itself has no knowledge directly of any underlying Java objects and doesn't care what backs the service.

If you were using an `xp:repeat` control you could bind to a backing `List` or other iterable collection from a backing Java class / bean. This would make far more sense if that's how you'll present the data. The logic shift is that specifically any time you update your `xp:repeat`, you *must* send an AJAX (XHR) wrapping around that `xp:repeat` tag, whereas a jQuery update from a REST service will get only the data response. There is *some* overhead to using AJAX to refresh part of the page (which literally is replacing part of the existing DOM with the newly fetched HTML and parsing the content), but at smaller scales, it's not a huge amount.

Using a REST service means that:

- your front-end implementation will be more consistent with the majority of the rest of the web development industry
- your back-end logic will be segregated, (ideally) making it more easy to port, migrate, or document

There's nothing wrong with implementing an `xp:repeat` (or friends) with backing Java on XPages, *especially* if you're using primarily XPages controls.

There are [many ways to implement a RESTful service in XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062424/basic-rest-service-for-my-xpage-application/36064707#36064707) and the reasoning behind [why to go for RESTful APIs in the XPages runtime](https://edm00se.io/xpages/rest-is-best/) is something both [myself](https://edm00se.io/servlet-series/) and many [others](https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/E8C88D2333F751BC85257DB00080AF32) have blogged about.

Comment: What a great answer. Summarising then, if I understand you correctly, in my case I am fine to carry on without REST services, but if I need to lighten the load and become more standardised I should consider REST Services. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: That's the basic takeaway. Glad I could help out.